# How to request a URL with a HTTP/1.5 protocol?

Tags: http

I have a test task from a potential employer. They want to me request a particular URL with HTTP/1.5 protocol.

Is that possible at all? If yes - how can I perform that?

Thank you!

Comment: There was HTTP/1.1 and then HTTP/2.0, there is no HTTP/1.5 as far as I know.

Comment: But technically you can request a URL reporting the protocol being used is version 1.5, even though it doesn't exist.

Comment: @Havenard how can this be done? I've try everything I could Google.

Comment: Google "http request example", or just see how the browser does it in the debug window (ctrl-shift-c, network tab).

Comment: You will notice the very first line it reports what HTTP version it is using, you can just put whatever. HTTP/super.mario.edition